# Zero eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the following problem:
Let $A \in \mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$ be a matrix and $f_A:\mathbb{C^{n\times n}} \to \mathbb{C^{n\times n}} $ be a linear map which is defined as $f_A(B)=AB - BA$. We have to show that, if every eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, then every eigenvalue of $f_A$ is $0$.

Since every eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to $0$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(x)=(-1)^n x^n$. Using the **Cayley-Hamilton** theorem , we have that $p_A(A)=(-1)^n A^n = 0 \Rightarrow A^n = 0$.

Can you give me a hint, on how to go on?

Comment: What is $f_A(f_A(B))$? And $f_A(f_A(f_A(B)))$?

Comment: $f_A(f_A(B))= A^2B-2ABA+BA^2$ and $f_A(f_A(f_A(B)))=A^3B - 3A^2BA+ 3ABA^2 - BA^3$ .

Comment: Do you notice something all the terms have in common?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's approach above certainly works. Here's an approach using a more sophisticated toolbox.  Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb C^n$. We find that
$$
f_A(e_ie_j^*) = (Ae_i)e_j^* - e_i(A^*e_j)^*\\
$$
Thus, the matrix of $f_A$ with respect to the basis $\{e_ie_j^*\}$ (taken in lexicographical order) is given by
$$
A \otimes I - I \otimes A^*
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. The eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^*$ are zero, so the above is the difference of two commuting nilpotent matrices, so it must be nilpotent itself.  That is, it must have only zero eigenvalues.